# Python Twisted reactor shared across python processes?

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

Trying to ask a basic yes / no question - to which the answer I fear is "no" - but if it is a "yes", seeking guidance on how!

I have an SMTP server written in Twisted Python. It works very nicely! Basic flow / sequence of function calls is something like:

```
script1.py
from mailserver import startReactor, startListener, stopListener, stopReactor
startReactor()
startListener("p25")
startListener("p26")
# Handle incoming connections etc until sigint receivedand then exit cleanly
stopListener("p25")
stopListener("p26")
stopReactor()
```

What I would like to do, in one or more separate python scripts (well, actually it'll be RobotFramework tests, but the principal is the same) is:

```
script2.py
from mailserver import startReactor, startListener, stopListener, stopReactor
startListener("p27")
# Handle incoming connections etc until all necessary stuff on p27 is complete
stopListener("p27")
```

And finally

```
script3.py
from mailserver import startReactor, startListener, stopListener, stopReactor
stopListener("p25")
startListener("p25custom)
# Handle incoming connections etc until all necessary stuff on "custom" p27 is complete
stopListener("p25custom")
startListener("p25)
```

So the idea is that script1.py is executed in the background,and then script2, script3 etc can be executed, "changing" the list of running listeners, but with these listeners attached to the reactor in script1....

By monitoring ps -xaf and netstat I can see the sockets opening in all scripts, and script1 exits cleanly ... but the sockets opened in script2 and script3  don't seem to close down...

In mailserver.py I maintain a dict of "runningListeners" (eg: `{'p25': <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Port'> of mailserver.ConsoleSMTPFactory on 25>}`) which gets added to / deleted from as startListener and stopListener get called as appropriate. However, this is obviously local to just script1, and not a "shared" dict between the 3 scripts... And I very much doubt the listeners started in script2 and script3 are actually as "attached" to the reactor started in script1 as netstat / ps might suggest - and as such probably not "useable" listeners...

So the yes no question - is it even possible to do what I am trying to do with multiple python scripts, and if so, can anyone offer a suggestion on how I can achieve this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: The answer to the question as asked, "can I share a reactor between processes", is "no". However, I *think* there's a way to do whatever it is you are trying to do using `spawnProcess` - I just can't figure out what it is that you actually want to *accomplish* by running "multiple scripts" as you put it.  Why not just run everything concurrently in your main program?

Comment: Hi @Glyph... I feared as much. What we *may* look to do is have script1 just running the "default" listener (p25) - and then have additional reactors start and stop with additional listeners as required....  Sort of feeling our way around in terms of WHHAT we want, as well as how to get it ;-)  Cheers!

Comment: Can you describe what you want without using the word "reactors"?  Because it's perfectly straightforward to start and stop additional *listeners* without starting and stopping multiple reactors.

Comment: We'll be wanting to start / stop reactors on demand (due to running concurrent test scripts, each requiring a listener configured differently - interface, port, SSL certs etc) - However, these test scripts will be run from RobotFramework tests - so a unique python process each test - effectively meaning the new listener would be "standalone". Does that shed any light on what we are looking to achieve? :)

Comment: Not really.  If you already have a unique process, can't you just import the reactor and do `reactor.run()`?  You shouldn't need anything special.  Do you mean you need to *control* the reactor from another process?

Comment: I think that's what we're looking at yes... So the box gets booted up, and we'll start the reactor, and the "standard" listener at that point. Then at arbitrary times, we'll want to run assorted test scripts using Robot Framework, some of which will want to start/stop additional listeners, and (this is the bit causing the headache I think!) - stop and restart the standard listener....

Comment: When you do `listenTCP` or `endpoint.listen`, you get back an `IListeningPort` object.  If you hold on to the first one you created, the "standard" listener, then you can just call `stopListening` on it and then `startListening` on it again.  Nothing in your scenario indicates a second process, unless "Robot Framework" (I still don't know what that is!) starts a process for you.  If it does, then there's a more fundamental problem of multiple concurrent tests simultaneously having a different idea about whether the "standard" listener is running.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make script1 'smarter' so that it runs the one single twisted reactor, but also have it running additional polling code that monitors either the file system or the network for bespoke 'instructions' sent from the other two scripts.

The instructions from the other two scripts would then instruct script1 about what to listen for (e.g. what ports etc to listen on and what handler code it should to run when an event occurs, possibly delegating using the subprocess module) and also indicate when a listener should be stopped.

So I guess the answer is erm yes, but its not easy so you may wish to reconsider your design first.